# Getting a value with a radio button

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out why when I submit this form via ajax for some reason it always wants to send 1 as the value and not the value of what is selected.

```
$('input[name="program_id"]').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        alert($(this).val());
    }
});
$("#pageOneSubmission").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var program_id = $('input[name="program_id"]:checked').length <= 0 ? 0 : $('input[name="program_id"]').val()

<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-md-6 lenght">
        <div class="calendar-stack fa-12x img-radio">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>
          <span class="calendar-day">26</span>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-radio">SELECT PROGRAM</button>
        <input type="radio" class="hidden" name="program_id" value="1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 lenght">
        <div class="calendar-stack fa-12x img-radio">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>
          <span class="calendar-day">46</span>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-radio">SELECT PROGRAM</button>
        <input type="radio" class="hidden" name="program_id" value="2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you sure this is the complete code for the click function?

Comment: `$('input[name="program_id"]').val()` Maybe you forgot a `:checked` there.